# Why is Firefox logging my user out automatically when using Redix OIDC?

Tags: reactjs, firefox, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm building a React app where I want to authenticate the user using OpenID Connect. In my dev environment the OIDC authority is a locally running instance of Identity Server 4.

I found a [Github repo](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc) which integrates the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library with Redux so I downloaded the [example repo](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example) and pointed it at my Identity Server. The only other change I made was to call a local API with my bearer token instead of the YouTube one used by the sample.

I have a Windows environment.

On Chrome and Edge the example works perfectly. I am able to authenticate and successfully call my local API using the bearer token. However, on Firefox, although the authentication works correctly and my API gets called successfully with results displayed, after a few seconds the app suddenly appears to sign the user out. (I say 'appears' because it behaves as though the user has been signed out but if I reload the page, the user is already authenticated).

---

*Note: I've crossed out a section here. This was a red herring. See **Update 1** below which describes how Firefox is adding a second iframe. A redirect URL wasn't registered for my client causing a redirect to IS4's error page which was responsible for these CSP warnings.*

<strike>Looking at the console logs, a key difference between Chrome and Firefox is a warning I'm seeing in Firefox:</strike>

> Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive.

This appears in the console a second or two after authenticating the user. I suspect this might be related to the iframe the Javascript OIDC client adds for checking the session. This iframe points at /connect/checksession on the identity authority.

If I navigate to this checksession URL in Firefox I get a Javascript error in the console:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at self ("script-src").

I don't see this error in Chrome.

The `Content-Security-Policy` for this page is `default-src 'none'; script-src 'sha256-VDXN0nOpFPQ102CIVz+eimHA5e+wTeoUUQj5ZYbtn8w='`

---

The only other bit of info I can provide is the console logs that are written as Firefox appears to sign the user out:

```
Action type: redux-oidc/USER_SIGNED_OUT 
Action payload: undefined
State before: Object { routing: {…}, oidc: {…}, subscriptions: {…} }
State after: Object { routing: {…}, oidc: {…}, subscriptions: {…} }
```

I'm hoping someone might be able to use this information to point me in the right direction because I'm really not sure what the problem is here. It seems the issue is within the Identity Server since it's reporting that Javascript error in Firefox on checksession, but I'm not sure what I can do about this.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Having delved deeper I've found the issue occurs when a second iframe gets added to the page calling the identity authority's *connect/authorize* endpoint with a URL like this: http://identity.domain.com/connect/authorize?client_id=js&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsilent_renew.html&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=9d87c43c58c84fddbde5fd9aa0f97df7&nonce=826fb8d6dc114549810584ddd01a3271&prompt=none. This only happens with Firefox. In Chrome and Edge this second iframe never gets added. Looking at the Identity Server logs I see the followings lines (amongst others) logged during the response to this *connect/authorize* call:

> No user present in authorize request
>
> Showing error: prompt=none was requested but user is not authenticated".

But I'm still no closer to understanding why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months later and I encountered this issue again. This time I worked out what the problem was. I was hosting my identity server locally on a non-localhost domain, but my React app was running on localhost. Therefore Firefox tracking protection was kicking in and blocking the Javascript OIDC client from accessing cookies on my identity server via its iframe. Switching to using identity server on a localhost port resolved the issue. I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this behaviour intermittently in Chrome when using oidc-client-js directly. In my case adding a call to *clearStaleState* on the UserManager seemed to stop this from happening.
EDIT: Specifically I added it before the call to getUser().

But since it was intermittent, it'd go away for a time if you logged out and cleared cookies and local/session storage, I can't guarantee this will fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just realised I failed to specify where I added clearStaleState. I added it before the call to getUser or any attempt to signInRedirect etc.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this hasn't made a difference. I wasn't calling `getUser` directly myself anywhere, and `signInRedirect` only in one place. Adding `clearStaleState` before it made no difference. Appreciate your time though.

Comment: Hello again. I actually may have tracked this one down now:
It's possible IdentityServer4 is not allowing your local host to checksession. Add to your Startup:

`services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None)`

Also make sure you aren't setting X-FRAME-OPTIONS headers to restrict to the same domain, and that can also break since localhost and identityserver won't be on the same domain.

Source: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/538

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I'm actually no longer getting this issue, but I can't for the life of me remember how I fixed it! (Or if it simply "went away"). I did do a lot of work around CORS settings at one point, but I certainly don't have that application cookie config change. I think you're fundamentally right, that the root cause is some sort of cross-origin blocking, but not sure this explains why the issue was only in Firefox. Cheers for the update though.